# How is this character on Clairvoyant's side?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the last episode S01E16 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, it is revealed that

> Agent Victoria Hand is a villain. She is either Clairvoyant herself or she is working for him. She is a high-level S.H.I.E.L.D. agent to order Melinda May for secret reports.

Mike Peterson clearly didn't kill her (Coulson's reasoning looks correct) and Victoria Hand changed course of the airplane after the encrypted line became disabled, but...

Previously in the show, when Agent Coulson told Skye about the alien (using which GH-325 was made), Melinda May intercepted it and reported it to someone: "He knows. I repeat, Coulson knows."
It says that the other person on the other side knows about the alien thing. I thought she reported to Director Fury. But, how could she report in such a way to the villain side which didn't know anything about the alien and the drug (Fury kept it secret; just to know about the secret they kidnapped Agent Coulson and injured Skye)?

Where's the catch?

Comment: First off, you really should try a little harder (read: at all) to avoid posting blatant spoilers for recent episodes without spoiler tags. It's just a general courtesy for people who don't get to watch the episodes real-time. Second, I know you're all excited and interested, but I don't know why you think any viewer has extra insight into characters and a story arc created explicitly for a new show.

Comment: @phantom42 It's not about character of Melinda May. Read the question body (if you have watched the episode). As for spoilers, I have edited the question. Trying to hide more.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: A good place to start would have been in the question title, which itself is a big spoiler. Downvote from me for undue consideration of spoilers.

Comment: @alexwlchan hey, I was still thinking..

Comment: At this point, we do NOT know that Melinda was reporting to Victoria, the Clairvoyant, or whomever the "villain" is. We can assume that the party on the other end of the encrypted line knows about GH-325, but that's all we know as of now.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm not sure even that's a safe assumption. 'He knows' could merely mean that Coulson knows *something* about how he was brought back, it's possible that she wasn't reporting about GH-325 specifically.

Comment: I'll also point out that, as far as I can tell, we still don't *know* that this character is the villain, merely that in the preview, they ordered Coulson's team killed. She could also believe that *they* are working for the Clairvoyant and believe them to be traitors. That's exactly the kind of plot twist that runs rampant through TV previews.

Comment: Thanks for spoiling a show I like to watch. It's not even slightly inconsiderate. I've warned you about this before, quite explicitly, when you spoiled *SHIELD* another time. It's just common courtesy.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Why did you read the question after seeing *agents-of-shield* tag?

Comment: Because the question title and the first few sentences are readable from the main page, with the tags appearing **underneath** the body of the question. I'd read a spoiler before I even knew what the question was about. After that I might as well read the question, even if just to chew you out for *repeatedly* spoiling this series, as well as asking silly questions about an ongoing series. It would be the equivalent of asking "who is that blonde woman in the shadows" after the *Star Trek: TNG* episode *Redemption*; no-one but the writing staff knows, so keep watching and you'll find out.

Comment: *Why did you read the question after seeing agents-of-shield tag?* Show of hands...err votes... How many people actually read tags before reading the title/summary of a question? Anybody?

Comment: Well, that episode debunked *all of that*.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In the last episode S01E17, it is clear that Melinda May wasn't on the villain side. She was really reporting to Director Fury. I was right.

A side note: Victoria Hand was also not a villain. The episode preview did a great job to mislead us. In reality, there was a misunderstanding and she assumed Coulson as villain.

Answer (score 9):

Now that we actually have answers, we can address your questions/concerns.

> Agent Victoria Hand is villain. She is either Clairvoyant herself or she is working for him.

Incorrect. She was revealed to have NOT been the Clairvoyant, NOT a member of HYDRA, and still loyal to S.H.I.E.L.D..

> She is a high-level S.H.I.E.L.D. agent to order Melinda May for secret reports.

Incorrect. She was a high-level S.H.I.E.L.D agent, but Melinda May was *not* secretly communicating with her.

> Mike Peterson clearly didn't kill her (Coulson's reasoning looks correct)

True: Mike Peterson clearly didn't kill Melinda May.

> and Victoria Hand changed course of the airplane after encrypted line became disabled, but...

Correct facts, incorrect correlation. The course change and the disabled encrypted line were coincidentally timed. Victoria had no knowledge of the encrypted line.

> Previously in the show, when Agent Coulson told Skye about the alien (using which GH-325 was made), Melinda May intercepted it and reported it to someone: "He knows. I repeat, Coulson knows."

True, aside from your use of the word "intercepted".

> [intercept](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intercept): to stop and take someone or something that is going from one place to another place before that person or thing gets there

She *overheard* the conversation and reported it to someone.

> It says that the other person on the other side knows about the alien thing.

Not necessarily safe assumption as Melinda did not specify what Coulson knew about, but ultimately true nonetheless.

> I thought, she reported to Director Fury. But, how could she report such way to the villain side which didn't know anything about the alien and the drug (Fury kept it secret; just to know about the secret they kidnapped Agent Coulson and injured Skye)?

Melinda *did* report to Director Fury. She was not reporting to HYDRA or any other villain.

> Where's the catch?

There was no catch. You just assumed incorrectly about everything.

Comment: As for the intercept thing, you're a typewriter in this tech era. Ever heard of *Communication Interception*? Oh, I have got a whole topic on that in my B. Tech. BTW, even if it was wrong, the correct protocol was to edit the question.

Comment: The way the scenes were presented, it was heavily implied that Melinda was reporting about Coulson knowing about the GHB-235. But exactly what she was reporting about was NOT specified. The way the scenes were presented, it was also heavily implied that Victoria Hand was either the Clairvoyant or working with him. That was wrong.

Comment: The point being that TV shows and movies specifically present things in misleading manners. Without Melinda specifically saying what Coulson knew, it is not a 100% lock.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Knock it off with the name-calling.

Comment: @Keen Unable to understand what you want to say..

Comment: @SachinShekhar The first comment used to contain name-calling, you called phantom42 an a-hole.  I've since edited that out.  Don't do that, one of the site rules is to be nice.